# NULL in a in UNION sql statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run the following query

```
with table_a as 
  (select '1' as column_name union select '2' union NULL)
select * from table_a;
```

I get:

```
Syntax error: unexpected 'NULL'.
```

Is there a way to insert the NULL as part of the SELECT above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` requires `SELECT`

```
with table_a as 
  (select '1' as column_name union select '2' union  SELECT NULL)
select * from table_a;
```

It is also possible to use `VALUES`:

```
with table_a(column_name) as 
  (SELECT * FROM VALUES ('1'),('2'),(NULL))
select * from table_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a query with one column all the time

```
with table_a as 
  (select '1' as column_name union select '2' union SELECT NULL)
select * from table_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add select before NULL, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

your SQL is malformed in general

you need SELECT ... FROM at least

```
select '1' as column_name from dual
union 
select '2' from dual 
union 
select NULL from dual;
```